# Map two Arrays and remove duplicated, keeping all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays which I want to manipulate. It will be used as a list.

Supposing its a system to show user which fruits are their favorite in a list. The system will display several fruits and she could mark the ones she likes, those will be attached to their position (index).

The other (null/untattached) positions will be populated will all other fruits available.

Below the code:

```js
let favoriteFruits = [null, null, 'banana', null, 'pineapple', null, null, null, null, null]
let allFruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'blueberry', 'strawberry']
let fruitsDisplayed = new Array(10)

allFruits = allFruits.filter(fruit => !favoriteFruits.includes(fruit))

fruitsDisplayed = favoriteFruits.slice(0)
fruitsDisplayed = fruitsDisplayed.map((fruit, i) => fruit == null ? allFruits[i] : fruit)

console.log(fruitsDisplayed)
```

Since the `favoriteFruits` are collected from `allFruits` (user can only choose her favorite if it's available on our **all** list), what happens when user favorite a given fruit (and item's index is stored on list), is that when I iterate the `allFruits`array to populate null spaces, it causes duplicated, which is what I want to avoid.

The expected result would be `fruitsDisplayed` be `favoriteFruits` ostored n their positions, added `allFruits` on all null spaces, **except the ones already favorited **. I can't think a way of doing it now.

Please notice that I have no control over `favoriteFruits`, which their fruits/indexes are set by the user.

What I'm trying to accomplish (null spaces are intended to be there):

**current result:**

(where is my blueberry??)

```
[
  "grape",
  "orange",
  "banana",
  "strawberry",
  "pineapple",
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

expected result

```
[
  "grape",
  "orange",
  "banana", // already favorited
  "blueberry",
  "pineapple", // already favorited
  "strawberry",
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined
]
```

I'm not a JavaScript expert, so if the answer questions any code practice I'm doing I'll happily edit to fit my needs.

Comment: I'd suggest if you are looking for this type of logic in many places in your app, you check out Lodash.js.  It has many chainable methods to do what you're looking for here.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan not really. I do want to merge them but I'd like to keep favoriteFruits position.

Comment: @jusopi thanks but I think this code is very possible with plain JavaScript. Adding a library here would be overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and delete the used items and build then a new array with `favoriteFruits`.

```js
var favoriteFruits = [null, null, 'banana', null, 'pineapple', null, null, null, null, null],
    allFruits = ['grape', 'banana', 'orange', 'pineapple', 'blueberry', 'strawberry'],
    fruitsDisplayed,
    fruitSet = new Set(allFruits),
    restFruit;
  
favoriteFruits.forEach(a => fruitSet.delete(a));
restFruits = [...fruitSet],
fruitsDisplayed = favoriteFruits.map(a => a || restFruits.shift());

console.log(fruitsDisplayed);
```

Comment: Being happily oblivious working in Coffeescript, I had not heard of Set.  Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

First form a third array which has items of both 1st and 2nd array.

```
      var arr3 = [];
     arr1.forEach(function(item){
        arr3.push(item);
      });
     arr2.forEach(function(item){
       arr3.push(item); 
     }
```

then use this function.

```
    var deduped = arr3.filter(function (el, i, arr) {
     return arr.indexOf(el) === i;
    });

   console.log(deduped);
```

Source: http://www.jstips.co/en/deduplicate-an-array/

Comment: it does dedupe but doesn't keep favoriteFruits position

Comment: I read the question carefully now. You actually don't even need to maintain two arrays. Just make one array which would be an array of objects and set a property isFavorate to be false by default. Set it to be true in case the user favorites it. This way you preserve the order and there's no need to maintain two arrays